# How to handle the about 0.15 second delay after using UIGestureRecognizer's delaysTouchesBegan method?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add double tap gesture for `UICollectionView`, but it conflicts with collectionView's `didSelectAtIndexPath` method. Then I turn to use the **delaysTouchesBegan**, when it's set to be true, the two events will not conflict. However, it brings a delay when I just single tap the cell and invoke the `didSelectAtIndexPath` method. Seems that the touch event becomes slow.

Is there any possible way to handle this delay issue?